# Using OpenCV in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to setup opencv in eclipse Luna. I have written a sample application as follows :

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

In my project properties i have included `/usr/local/include/opencv` in `(Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include Paths. )`

and `/usr/local/lib` in  `(Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Library Search Path. )`

My output of the command `pkg-config --cflags opencv` is `-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include`

and the output of `pkg-config --libs opencv` is

```
 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_viz -lopencv_adas -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_face -lopencv_latentsvm -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal
```

When I tried building my project i got the following errors.

```
‘imread’ was not declared in this scope 
‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope 
‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope    
‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope    
Function 'imread' could not be resolved 
Function 'imshow' could not be resolved 
Function 'namedWindow' could not be resolved
Function 'waitKey' could not be resolved
```

Can anyone help me fixing the problem and explain what is that I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

Try to change:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

To this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

You also need to link the Libraries (GCC C++ Linker » Libraries):

```
opencv_core
opencv_imgcodecs
opencv_highgui
```

You didn't say which version you are using, but as you have `-lopencv_imgcodecs`, you are probably using OpenCV 3. If you prefer, follow my instructions [here](http://rodrigoberriel.com/en/2014/10/usando-opencv-com-eclipse/). Also change from `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` to `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`.

Comment: 1) So should change also include directory `-I/usr/local/include`. 2) the `namedWindow` line can just be removed.