# error: ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 4.0 from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.0.0.zip
Below is the code

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    Mat frame0 = imread("hallo");
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -I/home/user/opencv/modules/core/include/ -I/home/user/opencv/modules/highgui/include/ -L/home/user/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

It throws me error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
test.cpp:11:32: error: ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope
     Mat frame0 = imread("hallo");
```

Any direction on how to resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OpenCV in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155611/using-opencv-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

put `#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>` and use

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -I/home/user/opencv/modules/core/include/ -I/home/user/opencv/modules/gapi/include/ -I/home/user/opencv/modules/highgui/include/ -I/home/user/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/include/  -L/home/user/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

to compile will solve the problem